# What started the Triforce conflict, and why does it keep happening?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

In the Twilight Princess, Ganondorf's [extended] monologue about the Triforce states that the "Chosen" (i.e. the ones bound to the Triforce) are destined to repeat this conlfict again [emphasis mine]:

> **When the Chosen Ones appear...**
>
> **They are always born into this world in perfect balance.**
>
> That is the destiny of the Chosen. That is the fate decreed by your Gods, the only path for those who bear their crests.
>
> **When this world brings forth another marked as you are...**
>
> **Know too, that it shall also be visited by one of my blood.**
>
> Do not think this ends here...
>
> The history of Light and Shadow will be written in blood!

<sup>[Source](https://youtu.be/LosGDVzR22o?t=2m14s)</sup>

This comes across as a kind of "prophecy", that this conflict will simply keep happening over and over again.

This explains the "rebirth" of Link through Hylia's history (Hero of Time; Hero of the Minish; Hero Chosen by the Gods; Hero of Light; etc), and Zelda's reincarnations as well, though Ganondorf seems to survive through history as the same person (likely due to his ties to the Triforce of Power).

I was under the impression that when the Goddesses created Hylia, the Triforce was a symbol of unity, and there was no mention of any evil intent in that event?

So my question is whay casued this in the first place, and why does this conflict keep arising?